# Spring MVC -- confused about declaring controller mappings

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC, so I'm confused.  I've used MVC in Struts, so I get the MVC pattern.  It's just that I'm now learning to do it in Spring, and I'm confused since the mapping is done differently.  I've tried consulting on-line tutorials, and I'm still not getting it.  Below is the low-down on my current problem.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks.

My JSP form (from GuestBook.jsp):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="comments" method="post" action="GuestBook.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="comment.name" maxlength="150" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="comment.message" rows="10" cols="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" value="Submit" /></button></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

From applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean name="getComments" class="com.controller.CommentController" />
```

From CommentController.java (just the pertinent parts):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/GuestBook.jsp")
public class CommentController {
    // Variables and getters and setters follow,
    // not part of the problem

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(@ModelAttribute Comment comment) throws Exception {
    // Method continues, but not part of the problem
```

Error report:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'getComments' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(GuestBook_jsp.java:256)
    at org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(GuestBook_jsp.java:207)
    at org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspService(GuestBook_jsp.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your object is not binding with the jsp form. Because you might not have put the object of your pojo class in the modelMap so that the `commandName="getComments"` attribute can bind the pojo fields with the form fields.

I have assumed here that your pojo class name is **GetComments**.

I recommend you to change the method signature of your controller method to the following.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView handleRequest(@ModelAttribute GetComments getComments) throws Exception {
// your code in the controller and the return statement of your model and view.
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also in your jsp instead of commandName, use `modelAttribute="getComments"`.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: My model is actually just called Comment.  I've tried some changes based on these suggestions, but they didn't work.  Is there anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: I think I fixed it, but I now have a slightly different problem.  If I can't figure it out, I will post a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `@ModelAttribute GetComments getComments` as the first parameter of your handle method.